My ubuntu don't start after install (initramfs)
Hi guys! I already try ubuntu, mint e and fedora and the result is the same alert! uid=bf1d6a72-3332-4552-8bf681c6ad1dce279 does not exit. dropping to a shell´ No uid ... boot image, But Windows OS 11, work without problems.
My notebook is Gigabyte PV25 v2, only have support to Windows OS (7,8 and 10).

Check the UUID and what does exist on your system; it's likely you've either made a change and removed that UUID  OR  your hardware has an issue that needs correction (a drive check needs to be performed if it's connected, ie. using the drives SMART capacity etc). Something on that device has changed; either from user decision OR hardware problem.

I solved the question! I do raid again in the hard disk and works, but Ubuntu don't see one disks but two, for this reason I choose another linux distro.
